# In Scala [2.11.6] is it possible to have one function param calculated from the value of another?

Tags: scala

While you can have default values for a function:

```
def someFunc(aLong: Long = 0l) {}
```

Is it possible to somehow reference the value of `aLong` while setting up a second parameter?

```
def someFunc(aLong: Long = 0l, optObj: Option[SomeObject] = Option(SomeObject(aLong)) {}
```

Of course this is a totally fabricated example as in this case you would likely just pass `SomeObject(aLong)` and extract the `Long` value from `SomeObject` within the function body.

The question still stands as i would like to know if this is possible and who it is done.

If you try to compile the above the compiler complains that `aLong` is not found.

Nonetheless I believe I've once tripped over how this is done (early or late initialization it might have been called and it might have sued the braces {} as part of the process as "anything" can be an expression in Scala.

I'm wondering if anyone can shed light on this, how it's done and what, if any, are the pitfalls of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's allowed, but they have to be in separate argument lists:

```
def someFunc(aLong: Long = 0l)(optObj: Option[SomeObject] = Option(SomeObject(aLong))) {}
```

No particular pitfalls that I'm aware of.